# How to create separate class with sensor results

Tags: java, android, sensors, android-sensors

I have w problem with simple code: In mainActivity i need check if sensor for example Light sensor is available on phone, and if is available i need to reed and show the results of this senson on screen, but code responsible for read data from sensor must be in separate class. I wrote simple code, but it doesn't work. When i run this code, my phone show me only : "Light level: 0.0". I'm beginner in programming so please help me..

Main class:

*public class MainActivity extends Activity {*

```
LightSensor mLightSensor = null;
protected SensorManager mSensorManager;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView wyswietl = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.res);

    mLightSensor = new LightSensor();

    mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

    if (mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT) != null){
        LightSensor lS = new LightSensor();

        wyswietl.setText("Light level: " + Float.toString(lS.lux));
    }
    else{

    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    mLightSensor.register();
}

@Override
protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    mLightSensor.unregister();
}
```

}

and LightSensor class:

public class LightSensor implements SensorEventListener {

```
SensorManager mSensorManager;
Sensor lightManager;
public float lux;

public Context context;

public void onCreateLight(Context context){
    this.context = context;
    mSensorManager = (SensorManager)context.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    lightManager = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT);


}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    lux = event.values[0];

}

public void register(){
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, lightManager, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}

public void unregister(){
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it, but you could possibly make a new method in your LightSensor class to return the lux variable to the main class
Something like:

```
public float getLux(){
   return lux;
}
```

and then in your "MainActivity" class you can call

```
float newLux = mLightSensor.getLux();
```

If it doesn't work I might have a slightly more complex solution.

Comment: Even when it works.. for now i always have window "Sensor application has been stopped" after running it..

Comment: Have you checked that your LightSensor works?
You can use the Log to check that you get some actual values from lux: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html

Answer (score 0):

You never call mLightSensor.onCreateLight();

How about changing onCreateLight to be your LightSensor class' constructor. That would solve the problem and not require you to remember to call onCreateLight.

```
public LightSensor(Context context){
    this.context = context;
    mSensorManager = (SensorManager)context.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    lightManager = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT);
}
```

Comment: can you help me and write how can i do this?

Comment: but what should i write as arguments of this constructor ?

Comment: I've edit my comment to show an example of the LightSensor constructor.